# Spark Multi-class classification -Categorical Variables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, categorical-data, multilabel-classification

I have a data set as a csv file. It has around 50 columns most of which are categorical. I am planning to run a RandomForest multi class classification with a new test data-set.

The pain-point of this is to handle the categorical variables. What would be the best way to handle them? I read the guide for Pipeline in Spark Website http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#example-pipeline which creates a DataFrame from a hard coded sequence also with the features a space delimited string. This looks very specific and I wanted to achieve the same thing on how they use HashingTF for the features using the CSV file i have.

In short I want to achieve the same thing as in the link but using a CSV file.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Data -> 50 features, 100k rows, most of it alphanumeric categorical
I am pretty new to MLlib and hence struggling to find the proper pipeline for my data from CSV. I tried creating a DataFrame from the file, but confused as to how I should encode the categorical columns. The doubts I have ar as follows

```
1. The example in the link above tokenizes the data ans uses it but I have a dataframe.
2. Also even if I try using  a StringIndexer , should I write an indexer for every column? Shouldn't there be one method which accepts multiple columns?
3. How will I get back the label from the String Indexer for showing the prediction?
5. For new test data, how will I keep consistent encoding for every column?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at the feature transformers http://spark.apache.org/docs/ml-features.html and in particular the StringIndexer and VectorAssembler.

Comment: If I use StringIndexer, how will I get back the original label for output?

Comment: You have the corresponding IndexToString to retrieve your original labels.

Comment: :Thanks! Is there any way to StingIndex multiple columns together?

Comment: Check out VectorIndexer